# Opening links in KDE: Broken Thunderbird or broken everything else

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, kde, kubuntu

On Kubuntu 11.10, when I set the KDE default browser to `/usr/bin/firefox` then clicking links in Thunderbird opens them in a new Firefox window instead of the already-open Firefox window. However, when I set the KDE default browser to `/usr/bin/firefox %U` then clicking links in Thunderbird does open them in the currently-open Firefox instances, but causes all other applications (Zim, LibreOffice) to open their links in a new Firefox window instead of the already-open Firefox window! Is there any way out of this catch-22?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set Thunderbird's `network.protocol-handler.app.http` preference to `/usr/bin/firefox %U`.